# Software for erasing "permanently deleted" files

Tags: gratis, windows-7, gui, wiping

I have around 100 files/ folders that I have permanently deleted, by sending them to the recycle bin and deleting them from there. With programs like Recuva I can easily get the files back, but I need them to be erased permanently. What program could I use?

The software I would like should be lightweight, free, fast, with a gui and for windows 7. Thanks.

**Note:** I know Glary Utilities has a function like this but I am looking for a different program. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want a really free and not only gratis tool you should use [**BleachBit**](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/features):

- it is free software (GPLv3)
- multi-platform: Linux & Windows
- easy GUI: just check what you want to do
- shred files/folders to prevent data recovery
- overwrite free disk space to hide previously deleted files
- and much more advanced features...

additional features for windows:

- portable app: run without installation
- built-in installer & updater for [*winapp2.ini*](http://winapp2.com/) (>2000 additional cleaners)

or if you want a special stand alone eraser-tool use [**Eraser**](http://eraser.heidi.ie/):

- free software (GPL)
- works on Windows XP SP3 and up (older version for Windows 98 to XP still available)
- erases files, folders and their previously deleted counterparts
- secure drive erasure
- extremely customizable scheduler

---

**but** keep in mind on a **SSD** (or other flash based media) every kind of **"secure deleting" [may be useless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_erasure#Limitations)**! - the worst case would be: you are erasing nearly nothing and just killing your device much quicker than necessary! ...this depends on the controller of the device!

Comment: AFAIK eraser deletes one by time?

Comment: @Pablo i haven't used it for years now, but AFAIK you can select multiple files like you do it for "default deleting" resp. moving to trashbin. and for tasks you can also use special include- and exclude-patterns. **||** if you are talking about the technical execution, i have no idea... but you can for sure have a look at [the source code](https://sourceforge.net/p/eraser/code/HEAD/tree/) and find out.

Comment: I tried Recuva + Bleachbit to delete permanently previously "just deleted" files. This method could be effective when you know exactly which files you want to recover and permanently delete. But if you have an undetermined number of files you want to recover and permanently delete because you dont remember how many they were, it could be not an effective method. In second rounds of Recovery of Recuva, I found files older than in the previous ones. Meaning in the first round for some reason it didnt find them

Comment: @Pablo i'm not sure about your point, but if you look for a tool completely dedicated to secure deleting, use eraser (there you can easily select the rounds/method for deleting)... if you are still concerned about your data use [FDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_encryption) as you have to do for all flash-drives anyway! - even if you are using only HDDs FDE is still the better way than fiddling around with "secure deletion".

Answer (score 4):

[CCleaner can securely erase free space!](https://www.piriform.com/docs/ccleaner/using-ccleaner/wiping-free-disk-space) It’s under Tools › Drive Wiper. (The product happens to be built by the same people behind Recuva, too.)